# QGIS python error using qgis2leaf and qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web, qgis2leaf, unicodeencodeerror

I'm trying to export a project using qgis2leaf and this error appears:

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2leaf\qgis2leafdialog.py", line 297, in export2leaf
    qgis2leaf_exec(self.outFileName, self.basemapName, self.basemapMeta, self.basemapAddress, self.width, self.height, self.extent, self.full_screen, self.layer_list, self.visible, self.opacity, self.encode2JSON,self.createcluster, self.webpage_name, self.webmap_head,self.webmap_subhead, self.legend,self.locate,self.address, self.precision, self.labels, self.labelshover, self.matchCRS, self.selected)   File "C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2leaf\qgis2leaf_exec.py", line 238, in qgis2leaf_exec
    in_raster = str(i.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xba' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.8.7-Wien Wien, 8a47921

```py
Python path: ['C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/grego/.qgis2//python', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:\\Users\\grego\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins', 'C:/Users/grego/Desktop/Granada Qgs']
```

I have also tried using the qgis2web plugin but I get a similar thing appearing

Qgis2web error:

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 139, in saveMap
    MainDialog.saveLeaf(self)
  File "C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 324, in saveLeaf
    cluster, json, params, popup)
  File "C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py", line 99, in writeLeaflet
    exportRasterLayer(i, safeLayerName, dataPath)
  File "C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletLayerScripts.py", line 52, in exportRasterLayer
    print "in_raster: " + in_raster
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xba' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.8.7-Wien Wien, 8a47921

Python path: ['C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/grego/.qgis2//python', 'C:\Users\grego\.qgis2\python\plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools', 'C:/Users/grego/Desktop/Granada Qgs']

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHsS3.jpg)

[image: Layers folder]

Here is what appears in the python console:

There were errors executing the algorithm.
Check the QGIS log to get more information
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified1457605619.1_prov.tif
Raster type: 2
prov_raster: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified01457605622.76_prov.tif
out_raster: C:\Users\grego\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis2web\qgis2web_1457605622.61\data\json_IGNPalomino1846modified0.png
There were errors executing the algorithm.
Check the QGIS log to get more information
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified01457605622.76_prov.tif
Raster type: 2
prov_raster: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified01457605653.46_prov.tif
out_raster: C:\Users\grego\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis2web\qgis2web_1457605653.24\data\json_IGNPalomino1846modified0.png
There were errors executing the algorithm.
Check the QGIS log to get more information
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified01457605653.46_prov.tif
Raster type: 2
prov_raster: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified01457605671.88_prov.tif
out_raster: C:\Users\grego\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis2web\qgis2web_1457605671.84\data\json_IGNPalomino1846modified0.png
There were errors executing the algorithm.
Check the QGIS log to get more information
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: c:\users\grego\appdata\local\temp\json_IGNPalomino1846modified01457605671.88_prov.tif

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the data you qant to export uses special characters that can't be encoded into the ascii characters. If your dataset uses characters like 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß' and so on you could try to replace them through e.g. 'ae', 'oe', (...) as a workaround.

Comment: Could you paste the qgis2web error? qgis2leaf has today been deprecated, but I'd like to fix errors in qgis2web.

Comment: I've added the qgis2web error, what is the data I have to replace characters of? Sorry, I'm new at this...

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable doing so, open C:/Users/grego/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletLayerScripts.py in a text editor, and comment out line 52 by adding a # at the beginning of the line : `#  print "in_raster: " + in_raster`. Restart QGIS, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it worked, but when the export is done I can't see my raster layer (an image of an old map) on top of the OSM layer, a tiny little square with a cross appears and that's all.

Comment: Interesting. Can you right-click the broken image in the browser, and choose Properties? See what path/URL the image has. Also look in the /layers folder of the output, and see if your raster is there.

Comment: I've put 2 images up on the post, It's in Spanish but I right click on the little box and no properties appear. Also there is a screenshot of the /layers folder with a java file.

Comment: The raster file has not been generated. Before starting qgis2web, can you open the python console in QGIS? Errors sometimes appear there.

Comment: There were no errors in python console when opening project, when I opened qgis2web and updated preview and then exported it all that I put on the post appears in the python console